# Search webpage that contain specific links

Tags: search-engine, data-mining, web-mining

Suppose I wan to search the web pages that contain the links I want.

I would normally use the link as the query and search it(Like in Google)

Note here, I just need to pages that contain the link.

But normally, the search engine would return results that are derived from my query.

In some cases, they will split my query into meaningful segments.

Like if I search *www.101domain.com/International* in Google.

Google will split the link into (*101domain,International*) which it think is more useful.

But I just need the raw result.

**PS:**

I am doing a web mining project, which finds the relationship between links and I will use such relationship to build up a graph.

Thanks for any suggestion!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For google try following query:
allinlinks: http://www.101domain.com/International
you can check more options in http://www.google.cz/advanced_search

Answer (score 1):

I suggest http://www.mnogosearch.org/. With this software you can easely download content of lot of sites to your database.

Answer (score -1):

101domain international isn't a real site on 101domain. The closest page I can even find to match that search is: [101domain.com/aboutus](https://www.101domain.com/aboutus.htm) maybe that's why it won't automatically take you there.

Comment: This is not really an answer for this question.